# Text analyzer with specific task

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the game as roulette where you can get  `"coin coin-ct"` or `"coin coin-t"` or `"coin coin-bonus"`. If it's possible, how can I know full times of 3 or 4 times in row repeats `"coin coin-ct"` variable? I am novice, sorry for misunderstanding.

As:

```
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721574 - 13</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721573 - 11</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721572 - 10</div>
</div>
```

Sample of full code (much more in real life):

```
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721574 - 13</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721573 - 11</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-bonus"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721572 - 0</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-t"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721571 - 6</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721570 - 9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on 3 or 4 times. I'm not sure what you're looking for. Also what have you attempted so far?

Comment: $(".coin.coin-ct").length; ?

Comment: Hello guys,

Thank you for answer. This is the game as roulette where you can get  "coin coin-ct" or "coin coin-t" or "coin coin-bonus". If it's possible, how can I know full times of 3 or 4 times in row repeats "coin coin-ct" variable?

As: 

<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721574 - 13</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721573 - 11</div>
</div>
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
  <div class="round">#2721572 - 10</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery selector for each row you have, select its children where their class are `coin coin-ct`.

**$(".row")**

A class selector which get all elements with class `row`. (`class="row"`)

**$(".row").each(function(itm){})**

An iterator for all elements have class `row`.

**$(this).children("div.icon-box")**

For selecting all children of selected element that are `div` and have class `icon-box`

Something like below:

```js
$(".row").each(function(itm) {
  $(this)
    .children("div.icon-box")
    .each(function(obj) {
      console.log($(this).children(".coin.coin-ct").length)
    });
  console.log("-----------------------------");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721574 - 13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721573 - 11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-bonus"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721572 - 0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-t"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721571 - 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721570 - 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721574 - 13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721573 - 11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-bonus"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721572 - 0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-t"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721571 - 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721570 - 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721574 - 13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721573 - 11</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-bonus"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721572 - 0</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-t"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721571 - 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="icon-box">
    <div class="coin coin-ct"></div>
    <div class="round">#2721570 - 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Read [JQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), 
 [each function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), 
 [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Hope this helps you.